# jQuery Autocomplete - without terminating at whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, whitespace

What's the simplest way to make jQuery UI autocomplete handle multiple words? As of now, a space will terminate the autocomplete.

```
$.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "http://localhost/some_json",
                success:
                    function(response) {
                        $("#title").autocomplete({
                            source: response,
                            minLength: 2,
                            select: function (event, ui) {


                            }

                        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                            //
                        }

                    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example, because it's difficult to understand what's happeneing from here. Looking at your code the space should not prevent the autocomplete

Comment: Are you referring to this AC? - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I was referring to this example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote and to my experience

Comment: It's normal behaviour for suggestions to not work when space is used with autocomplete I want to know how to be able to use it with space ie. multiple words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set-up this basic example:

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>     <input id="tags">

var availableTags = ["Action alpha", "Action omega", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

And for me the autocomplete continues after the space. Try digiting `Action a` and you will se e the correct suggestion under the input

Comment: Are you using this? - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Argh, I had AC matching against filenames, sorry

Comment: @amiawizard sorry i had also preparade a jsfiddle but i forgot to link it! Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#tagnames").autocomplete("/tags/filter",
{
    max: 6, 
    highlightItem: true, 
    multiple: true, 
    multipleSeparator: " ",  
})
```

To enable auto-complete for multiple words you should set options `multiple`: `true` and `multipleSeparator`: `" "`

Comment: Wrong autocomplete, you're referring to the plugin not UI